# Open Parent Class as Child Class (SD Fat Library)

Tags: arduino-mega, sd, fat

I'm currently using the [SDFat library](https://github.com/greiman/SdFat) and am passing a global `FatFile`

[image]

I if have a function that requires an `SdFile` type and I know that a given instance of `FatFile` is a valid `SdFile` what is the best way to reopen `FatFile F` as `SdFile J`?

Right now I'm doing:

```
SdFile ActiveFile;  //Global Active File
...
void SDRun (FatFile &RunFat)
{
  SdFile RunRoot;
  RunRoot.open("/", O_READ);
  ActiveFile.close();
  ActiveFile.open(&RunRoot,RunFat.dirIndex(),O_READ);
  ....
```

However, this only works when `RunFat` is in the root directory.

Answer (score 1):

If `RunFat` is an instance of `SdFile` you can just cast it:

```
SdFile& RunRoot = dynamic_cast<SdFile&>(RunFat);
```

`RunRoot` and `RunFat` are now the exact same file in the exact same state (no need to open it or anything) but seen as an `SdFile` not a `FatFile`.

Comment: Ok, doing `SdFile& RunRoot = dynamic_cast<SdFile&>(RunFat);` I get an error `cannot dynamic_cast 'RunFat' (of type 'class FatFile') to type 'class SdFile&' (source type is not polymorphic)`

Comment: Did you make sure you got all the `&` in the right places?

Comment: I have, I've also tried a few variants, but the dynamic cast continues to give me a `source type is not polymorphic` error.

Comment: Maybe it's not a proper child->parent relationship then. Or it's not really a class, or something?